# How magical powers would affect the distribution of wealth

Tags: society

In the world I'm building, a certain amount of humans have the ability to gain magical powers. I'm still playing with the exact ratio, but let's say around 20% for now. These magical powers would contribute greatly to the economy, as those with powers could produce enchanted materials, grow food at much greater efficiency, mine valuable materials with magical efficiency, etc.

With such abilities, 20% of the population would have a much higher impact on the common good and economy than the 80% that do not have powers. My question is, what place do those 80% have in the economy and in society? There is no need to be a farmer or a miner, or a builder with such things magically automated. Should the wealth that the 20% create be redistributed to the 80%? Perhaps something akin to universal basic income?

Any thoughts on the societal impacts of such a high disparity between individuals' personal production?

Comment: Comparative advantage suggests there may still be a need for farmers or miners, unless magic users have no opportunity cost and can fill literally every role in society. If magic users are 100% faster at mining but only 10% faster at farming, it's most productive for magic users to mine exclusively and trade with non-magical farmers rather than trying to do everything themselves (magic users alone cannot produce as much as magic users plus non-magic users).

Comment: We try to avoid closing the questions of new users. This question is asking for an analysis that's very subjective and opinion-based. We could compare the magicians and their ability to be more productive to those who posses wealth today. We could also compare them to slaves, who are the producers for those who own/control them. Too much of this question depends on the structure of your world, which you have not yet defined. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... As you continue to use this Stack, please bear in mind that our sweet spot is answering questions of the form, "I've decided that the rule of my world is X, can you help me rationalize it?" You're asking a question of the form, "I don't know where my world can go, can you help me make the decision?" Thus, we need you to decide what role your magicians play in your society, including their political and business roles - we can help you rationalize the details after that. But asking us what role they should play is often too opinion-based or too story-based to avoid closure.

Comment: It's also important to know *how* magic helps grow food at a much greater efficiency. Can magic increase the yield of the crops, or make it so the crops require less sunlight/water/nutrients? Can the crops be harvested and processed at an equal rate?

Comment: It's hard to really say what the dynamics would look like without further detail about... well pretty much everything about your world. The distribution of wealth in real life also isn't tremendously impacted by skillsets; CEOs vary greatly in intelligence and skill within various categories, teachers and university professors are very intelligent yet not paid all that well, and the main reason that software developers are paid so well is because of the excessively high demand for them relative to the supply. Supply and demand dictate wealth distribution more than anything else.

Comment: Unfortunately the best answer is "it depends"  How egalitarian vs hierarchic is the society? How much automation does the magic permit? Due to specialization and exchange there will always be some value (maybe too low to pay rent) for people to be non idle.  Overall this question as is, is too open ended to be anything but subjective.

Answer (score 0):

#### No Effect

Magic in and of itself has no bearing on the "distribution of wealth" per se. Magic is really no different than technology or any other advantageous phenomenon. Magic is also neither a panacaea nor a eutopic wonderwork. In other words, it's just a tool. If you have the tool and know how to use it, you've got an advantage in the economy. Given that your proposal seems to be leaning towards magic as a kind of assembly line, I'd argue that if a technothurge is copying some book for sale and his original is flawed, then so will his copies be flawed. Magic doesn't correct problems, it just propagates the problems already in the system. Similarly, if the original PDF file is screwy, any copies of the book made through technological means will not suddenly become perfect.

The question then reverts to a simple real world inquiry. If 20% of the people have "magical powers" called (non-woke) Education, Drive, Ethics, Creativity, Experience and these are the ones driving the economy; while the 80% are content to do their thing; then we can see that wealth distribution will follow roughly the same pathways in your fictional world that it does in the real world. Those with the power advantage will tend to be the ones who create wealth.

The actual pathways of wealth distribution largely boil down to the essential economic / social / governmental types that we all know and love to despise.

As for the place of the 80% within the economy, they'll have the same place whether the tool is magical or technological. Magically enhanced turnips still need to be harvested, cleaned, processed, packed, distributed, sold (several times perhaps), cooked, prepared, processed and served. Every step along the way requires some kind of servicing: maintenance, cleaning, quality control, engineering, waste & resource management, book keeping, etc. All the people who specialise in those kinds of service occupations need servicing as well: education, health, food service, religious, spiritual, mental support, construction, contracting, plumbing, technical service, etc.

Each individual in any society stands at the head of a polydimensional and interlinked pyramid of interlaced social fibres the nodes of which are both the individual's own pyramid structure and simultaneously a large number of other people's own pyramid structures.

Answer (score 0):

## It wouldn't tip the scales that far, if at all

Assuming all else is equal, there would be little noticeable difference from real life. Yes, it's true that many of the high-paying jobs would be ones that require a caster due to their relatively low supply, but the thing is that magical powers are not rare enough to tip the scales strongly in favor of casters. At 20% prevalence, they are still plenty replaceable.

There will still be great opportunities for normals because there will undoubtably be activities where magic is not very helpful. Consider CEOs in real life: they very rarely have more than one or two of the skills that are among their necessary employees, yet because of their ability to manage others, take risks, and drive business decisions, they are (sometimes) rewarded with exorbitantly high salaries. Normals would still find ways to outcompete their caster counterparts, and on more than just price point. Inventors will invent new machines that do the same job as magic, but more efficiently or at lower cost. Meanwhile, many normals will take the jobs (often good jobs) that casters feel are below them (think blue collar vs white collar work. e.g. plumbers are paid very well)

It's also a distinct possibility that casters would develop poor work ethic and/or poor money management skills much like the rich and gifted kids IRL. They may feel as if everything will be a breeze due to their powers only to come to the realization that whatever advantage their magic would have granted them is nullified and then some by their laziness and unlikeable personality.

### Of course, this all depends on just how good magic is

If magic is too good, there is little reason for non-casters to do anything... but rather than this creating income inequality, this would breed resentment from the casters who are expected to carry the dead weight of the others because there would be nothing truly substantial that the normals could do in exchange for the labor of the mages.